# Sort and Search in belongs_to and has_many through Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, search, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

I have two models, post and book, associated through a third, kms.

association looks like :

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :year, :author, :book_ids
  has_many :kms
  has_many :books, through: :kms   
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :kms
  has_many :posts, through: :kms
end

class Km < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :count, :book_id, :post_id
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :post

   def self.search(search)
      if search
        case type
           when "Name of Book"
                where('book.name ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
           when "Name OF Post"                                
                where('post.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")   
            end
      else
        scoped
      end            
  end
end
```

here `_kms.html.erb` looks like:

```
<%= form_tag list_km_path, :method => 'get', :id => 'kms_search' do %>
    <p style="float:right;display:inline;">
        <%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
        <%= select_tag "fieldtype", options_for_select([ "Name of Book", "Name of Post"], "Name of Book"),  :style => 'width:150px;' %>
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search],  :style => 'width:200px;', :placeholder => "search..." %>
    </p>
<% end %>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
       <th><%= sortable "book.name", "Name of Book" %></th>
       <th><%= sortable "post.name", "Name of Post" %></th>
    </tr>
  </thead >
  <tbody>
    <% for km in @kms %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= km.book.name %></td>
      <td><%= km.post.name %></td>

    </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

here `kms_controller.rb` looks like:

```
   def index
     @per_page = params[:per_page] || 10
     @kms  = Km.search(params[:search],params[:fieldtype]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => @per_page, :page => params[:page])
   end

  def sort_column
    Km.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "book.name"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
```

**Problem 1 :**

I want to search name of book and name of post on form kms_search, but it's not working and there is no response when I select fieldtype name of book and type the name of the book on field, as well as name of post.

**Problem 2 :**

I want to sort name of book and name of post, but I have an error:

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "book"
LINE 1: ...kms" ORDER BY book...
                         ^
: SELECT  "kms".* FROM "kms" ORDER BY book.name asc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Can anybody help me, how do I resolve my problem?

Thanks.

Comment: For sorting you can use [sort_this](https://github.com/spullen/sort_this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pluralize all of your table names when querying with SQL:

```
where('books.name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
```

prob 2.

Not sure if this is going to work, but try it like this:

```
   <th><%= sortable "books.name", "Name of Book" %></th>
   <th><%= sortable "posts.name", "Name of Post" %></th>
```

and

```
def sort_column
    params[:sort].downcase == "posts.name" ? "posts.name" : "books.name"
end
```

and in your index action:

```
Km.search(params[:search],params[:fieldtype]).joins(:book).joins(:post).uniq.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
```

Comment: I have an error :
`PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "books"
LINE 1: SELECT  "kms".* FROM "kms"  WHERE (books.name ILIKE...
                                           ^
: SELECT  "kms".* FROM "kms"  WHERE (books.name ILIKE '%IPA%') ORDER BY
 book_id asc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0`

Comment: is that method `def self.search(search)` in your books model or in your km model? if in your km model, you have to join the books table with `.joins(:books).where..`

Comment: using `:book` not `:books`
great, thanks.. solved for search method, one problem is sort not resolved.

Comment: sort method, **problem 2**

Comment: `undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass` on `line 14` , see `.joins(:books).joins(:posts).uniq.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)`

Comment: sorry, do `.joins(:book)` and `.joins(:post)`

Comment: `undefined method +' for nil:NilClass` on line 14 , see `.joins(:book).joins(:post).uniq.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28328/discussion-between-zippie-and-anonymousxxx)